# Background shows progress of input characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field and I want that the `background` of the input field fill every time when some type something in. So the background shows the progress of the input field.

```
    <input class="controlinput" id="title" maxlength="156" data-class=".title" type="text">
```

156 characters are the 100%;

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#title").on('keyup', function(){
  var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
  var percentage = Math.floor($(this).val().length / maxlength * 100) + '%';
  $("#percentage").text(percentage);
  $("#bg").css({width: percentage});
})
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

#bg { 
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:0%;
  height:16px;
  top:1px;
  z-index:0; 
}

#title { 
  padding-right:30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  background:transparent;
}

#percentage { 
  font-size:10px; 
  color:#777; 
  position:absolute; 
  right: 5px;
  top:3px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="controlinput" id="title" maxlength="156" data-class=".title" type="text">
  <span id="percentage"></span>
  <div id="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works works perfectly thanks :D. But is there any way to make that the background of the input is showing the process?  I mean when i type in anything, the background is  showing the process from left to right. Sorry for the bad example my english isn't that good.

Comment: Yes its almost right but i need this to happen for the background of my input field. so when i type in my stuff the background should do the same as the #bg container does

Comment: As far as I know - you can't set background for part of the input field. That's why I used `#bg` div to mimic this behavior